# Return from the function wasn't assigned to the $scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my controller:

```
$scope.mainModel = getReviews({model:mainModelArr[1]});
$scope.compareModel = getReviews({model:compareModelArr[1]});

function getReviews(data) {
    $http.post(url, data)
    .success(function(res) {
        formatReviews(res)
    })
    .error(function(err) {
        console.log("Something went wrong: "+err);
    });
}

function formatReviews(data) {
    var review = data[0];
    review.sumReviews = (review.sumReviews/review.ratingAvg).toFixed(0);
    review.sumRecommend = (review.sumRecommend/review.sumReviews*100).toFixed(1);
    review.ratingAvg = (review.ratingAvg).toFixed(1);
    console.log(review); // logs message fine 
    return review;
}
```

These functions work fine, **logs** `review` var., but somehow it didn't assign `review` variable neither to `$scope.mainModel` nor to `$scope.compareModel`.

NOTE: I know that it wasn't assigned, because it's never showed up in HTML:

```
<p>{{mainModel}}</p>
```

**What did I do wrong and how can I fix that?**

Comment: A good read [Promises in AngularJS, Explained as a Cartoon](http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax requests works Async, angularjs use promises to handle this requests

```
$scope.mainModel = undefined;
$scope.compareModel = undefined;

getReviews({model:mainModelArr[1]}).success(function(res){
    $scope.mainModel = formatReviews(res);
});

getReviews({model:compareModelArr[1]}).success(function(res){
    $scope.compareModel = formatReviews(res);
});
```

If you `return` post request, you can handle it anywhere, where you call `getReviews` method

```
function getReviews(data) {
    return $http.post(url, data)
    .error(function(err) {
        console.log("Something went wrong:", err);
    });
}

function formatReviews(data) {
    var review = data[0];
    review.sumReviews = (review.sumReviews / review.ratingAvg).toFixed(0);
    review.sumRecommend = (review.sumRecommend / review.sumReviews * 100).toFixed(1);
    review.ratingAvg = (review.ratingAvg).toFixed(1);   
    console.log(review); // logs message fine 
    return review;
}
```

Comment: @MichaelVayvala i used `success` not `then`

Answer (score 1):

Since asynchronous code won't allow you simply return the value, you should work with promises using their `then` methods:

```
getReviews({model: mainModelArr[1]}).then(function(data) {
    $scope.mainModel = data;
});

getReviews({model: compareModelArr[1]}).then(function(data) {
    $scope.compareModel = data;
});

function getReviews(data) {
    return $http.post(url, data)
    .success(formatReviews)
    .error(function(err) {
        console.log("Something went wrong: "+err);
    });
}
```

Comment: @MichaelVayvala Ops, forget to return from `getReviews`.